# get collection featured products

Tags: magento-1.9

Im trying to retrive all my products with attributed of featured of yes (1), but int working my code:

```
<?php
$_products = $this->getProductCollection();
$_products->addAttributeToSelect('featured',1);


?>
<?php if ($_products && $_products->getSize()): ?>
    <div class="widget widget-new-products">
        <div class="widget-title">
            <h2><?php echo $this->__('Produtos em Destaque') ?></h2>
        </div>
        <div class="widget-products">
            <?php echo $this->getPagerHtml() ?>
            <?php $_columnCount = $this->getColumnCount(); ?>
            <?php $i=0; ?>
            <ul class="products-grid products-grid--max-<?php echo $_columnCount; ?>-col-widget">
                <?php foreach ($_products->getItems() as $_product): ?>
                    <li class="item<?php if(($i-1)%$_columnCount==0): ?> first<?php elseif($i%$_columnCount==0): ?> last<?php endif; ?>">
                        <?php $_imgSize = 210; ?>
                        <?php // The image size is locked at 210 for this for display purposes. CSS has it at 75% which should equate to 278px?>
                        <a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->stripTags($_product->getName(), null, true) ?>" class="product-image">
                            <img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->resize(210) ?>" alt="<?php echo $this->stripTags($_product->getName(), null, true) ?>" />
                        </a>
                        <div class="product-info">
                            <h3 class="product-name"><a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->stripTags($_product->getName(), null, true) ?>"><?php echo $this->helper('catalog/output')->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getName() , 'name') ?></a></h3>
                            <?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($_product, true, '-widget-new-grid') ?>
                            <?php echo $this->getReviewsSummaryHtml($_product, 'short') ?>
                            <div class="actions">
                                <?php if ($_product->isSaleable()): ?>
                                    <button type="button" title="<?php echo Mage::helper('core')->quoteEscape($this->__('Add to Cart')) ?>" class="button btn-cart" onclick="setLocation('<?php echo $this->getAddToCartUrl($_product) ?>')"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?></span></span></button>
                                <?php else: ?>
                                    <p class="availability out-of-stock"><span><?php echo $this->__('Out of stock') ?></span></p>
                                <?php endif; ?>
                                <ul class="add-to-links">
                                    <?php if ($this->helper('wishlist')->isAllow()) : ?>
                                        <li><a href="<?php echo $this->getAddToWishlistUrl($_product) ?>" class="link-wishlist"><?php echo $this->__('Add to Wishlist') ?></a></li>
                                    <?php endif; ?>
                                    <?php if($_compareUrl=$this->getAddToCompareUrl($_product)): ?>
                                        <li><span class="separator">|</span> <a href="<?php echo $_compareUrl ?>" class="link-compare"><?php echo $this->__('Add to Compare') ?></a></li>
                                    <?php endif; ?>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: What context is this in (i.e. what class is `$this`)?

Comment: is Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_Widget_New

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

```
$_products = Mage::getModel("catalog/product")->getCollection()->addAttributeToSelect("*");
$_products->addAttributeToFilter('featured',1);
```

in place of

```
$_products = $this->getProductCollection();
$_products->addAttributeToSelect('featured',1);
```

Comment: is blank, nothing appears

Comment: Please check with updated code. It should work for you.

Comment: @Pedro, did you get the solution for your issue?

Answer (score 0):

There be addAttributeToFilter not addAttributeToSelect